# Sencha Touch 2 - storing values from json using proxy not working for me

Tags: ajax, model, proxy, extjs, store

im new to Sencha Touch 2, im trying to store values from json using store and models by proxy, but don't no where im wrong

**My model**

```
Ext.regModel('Product', {
    fields: [
        {name: 'name',        type: 'string'},
        {name: 'description', type: 'string'},
        {name: 'price',       type: 'float'},
        {name: 'image_url',   type: 'string'},
        {name: 'in_stock',    type: 'boolean'}
    ]

});
```

**My store**

```
Dzineapp.BlogStore = new Ext.data.Store({
model: 'Product',
autoLoad: false,
proxy: new Ext.data.AjaxProxy({
    type: 'ajax',
    url: 'http://localhost/products.json',
    reader: {
        type: 'json',
        root: 'products'
    },
    writer: {
        encode: true,
        type: 'json'
    }
    })
});
```

**Products.json**

```
{
    "products": [
        {"name": "Some Product",    "price": 9.99, "image_url": "product1.jpg", "in_stock": true},
        {"name": "Another Product", "price": 7.50, "image_url": "product2.jpg", "in_stock": true},
        {"name": "A third product", "price": 2.35, "image_url": "product3.jpg", "in_stock": false}

    ]
}
```

**My Views**

```
 Dzineapp.blogPanel = new Ext.List({
            id: 'bloglist',
            store: Dzineapp.BlogStore,
            itemTpl: '<div class="contact">{name}</div>'
        });
```

But my App dosent show any values,  any one can help me where im doing the mistake.. im just starter in sencha

Answer (score 1):

1) You should use Ext.create() instead of new ... (but this should work anymway)

2) You should add ' around the store value in your list config

3) Check that you add your store to the stores[] in your app.js or add a require in your list.

4) With firebug/chrome dev tools check that your request is working ok (HTTP : 200) and that you get your json.

Hope this could help

Answer (score 0):

Can you update your store as below

```
Dzineapp.BlogStore = new Ext.data.Store({
   model: 'Product',
   autoLoad: true,
   proxy: {
     type: 'ajax',
     url: 'http://localhost/products.json',
     reader: {
       type: 'json',
       root: 'products'
     }
   }
});
```

I hope so it works.

We have to load the store to display the data.

Thanks,
Swathi.

Answer (score 0):

In your store configuration instead of using

```
root: 'products'
```

Try using

```
rootProperty: 'products'
```